# Cannot do POST request from Perl

Tags: perl, google-app-engine

I have a normal page in the internet which has this layout

```
<form method="POST">
<textarea rows="30" cols="70" name="spytext" id="spytext"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

And I am trying to post on this page, from localhost, using Perl.

At first I got a status `302 Found` and I added the following line to the browser in order to follow any redirect:

```
push @{$browser->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';
```

And now my Perl code looks something like this

```
my %Fields = ("spytext" => "Will Bontrager");

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $Browser = new LWP::UserAgent;

push @{$Browser->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';

my $Page = $Browser->request(POST "http://myGAEFictiveLink.appspot.com/spypage",\%Fields);

if ($Page->is_success) { print $Page->content; }
else { print "\nUnsuccessful " . $Page->message; }
```

Therefore, on my "spypage" I POST this field named "spytext" with a value, and I expect to retrieve what I would normally get after posting it in the browser (an HTML paragraph with a message).

After running the script, it proves to be a successful POST but the page content shown is exactly the initial page "spypage" instead of another page, which usually comes after POSTing in the page interface.

So I guess it didn't really post, or it didn't post on my target page.

How can I force Perl to post on that page?

Comment: To be clear: You have a `html` page that will post to a local (within the same web-root) `perl` script that will then redirect to a GAE page?

Comment: I run a perl script locally, with Perl I try to post to a page in the internet 
(which happens to be my page), then (with Perl) I retrieve the result after performing POST. It gives me the same page as if no POST happened.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the link you are posting to for troubleshooting?

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand your question. I have edited it, and I hope it still says what you intended. You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program, and it is best to follow the advice in [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) so that people used to writing Perl can understand what you have written. The line beginning `my $Page` is trying to call a subroutine `POST` that doesn't exist. You should fix that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look at it in my `REST` console to figure it out, but your page requires `HTTPS` and you are sending via `HTTP` in your `perl` script so you are getting redirect (302) to the secure version and that is acting like a `GET` request. Change the `URL` in your script to use HTTPS and it will work as shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my %Fields  = (
        spytext => 'Will Bontrager',
    );

my $url = 'http://myGAEFictiveLink.appspot.com/spypage';


my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->post( $url, %Fields );

if ($res->is_success) {
    # If successfully (200 status code) do this
    my $content  = $res->decoded_content();
    print $content . "\n";

} else {
    print "Status Code: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
    print "Final URL: " . $res->request()->uri() . "\n";
}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<p>Okay, now expect for an email</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a loooooot.. what a silly mistake.. can I ask you a favor.. please remove my link from your code, the one with appspot. Thank you

Comment: @Madrugada, I removed it, but please note the reason I originally asked is because `Trusted Users` (> 20,000 points) can see the deleted  comments, questions, answers so if it is sensitive you should not share it, but a replacement code. From my experience on this site though people are generally not malicious in nature so I tend to trust them with any public facing links, etc... Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's not a sensitive page, but I wouldn't like random people (visitors) making tests on it either. I also trust super users of this site.